# Conditional Probability Uniform Bivariate Transformation Distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, bivariate

I'm reviewing probability theory from years ago and am a bit rusty. I'm not sure how to calculate the conditional probability for a uniform distribution after a bivariate transformation.

Suppose X and Y both follow a Uniform$(0,2)$ distribution. For the transformation $U=X+Y$ and $V=X$, I'll then have the following joint PDF:
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{4}, & \text{if $0<V<U<4$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}

How would I calculate the conditional probability $P(V<.2|U=1.5)$? I'm likely missing something very intuitive. I've had someone say that U follows a $U(0,1.5)$ distribution and thus $P(V<.2) =\frac{1}{1.5} * .2$ but that doesn't seem right to me. I'd have to multiply by $\frac{1}{4}$ at some point, right?

Edit:

Conditional. on $f(V|U)$

First found the marginal of $U$ as follows:

\begin{cases}
    \frac{u}{4}, & \text{if $0<U<2$}\\
    \frac{1}{2}-\frac{u-2}{4}, & \text{if $2<U<4$}\\
    \ 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Since $U=1.5$, the conditional $f(V|U=1.5)=\frac{f(U,V)}{f(U=1.5)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{u}{4}}=\frac{1}{1.5}$

So the probability $(V<.2|U=1.5)=$

$$\int_{0}^{.2} \frac{1}{1.5} dv = .2*\frac{1}{1.5} - 0*\frac{1}{1.5}=.133$$

Comment: You are missing the independence of $X$ and $Y$. The distribution of $U$ is not uniform. Find the conditional density of $V$ given $U$ and hence the probability.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I added the conditional to my post. My process was correct, right? Sorry I know this is simple stuff, just been so long.

Comment: Why in the joint PDF you have $0<V<4$? Shouldn't it be $0<V<2$ since $V=X$?

Comment: I think you can find everything you need here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUBlhsJpf1g

Comment: @ping Oh, yes. It should be 0<V<2 and 0<V<U<V+2 right?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. I’ve tried to draw the domain of the joint pdf of U and V

Comment: @ping Doesn't your drawing confirm that it's 0<V<2 and 0<V<U<4?

Comment: Yes both conditions together

Answer (score 0):

This follows my comment (using the approach shown in the Youtube video). Once you have the joint you can calculate the conditional.

Sorry for the typo. Of course, $g_2(X,Y)=X$, and not $Y$.

[image]